# How do I customize the search result page?

Tags: 7, nodes, search

I have customized the teaser view of my content types and the page view. Now I need to use the teaser view for the search results page. By default, Drupal displays a full text jumbled mess for each result, I need to be able to customize the look of each one per content type. I don't want to change HOW drupal gets the results, just how it displays them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can override theme_search_results(), or theme_search_result().

The first is the theme function that is invoked for the search result page, while the second is the theme function that is invoked to render a single result. Both the theme functions use a template file ([search-results.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-results.tpl.php/7) in the first case, [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-result.tpl.php/7) in the second case).

search-result.tpl.php would use `$info_split['type']` in Drupal 6, which contains the node type. In the latest Drupal 7 version, `$info_split['type']` is not anymore passed, but search-result.tpl.php still gets `$result['node']`, in the case the search is done for nodes; `$result['node']->type` is then the content type of the node.

To notice that Drupal 7, and higher, allows the modules to implement [hook_search_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.api.php/function/hook_search_page/7), but it is a hook used by a module that integrates with the Search module, not from a module that wants to change the result page for results returned by another module.
Also, on Drupal 7, each theme function uses a preprocess function, which in this case would be [hook_preprocess_search_results()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7.x) and [hook_preprocess_search_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7.x). They are helpful in the case you just need to edit the value of what passed to the template file.

Comment: Is there a way to theme search results using views or panels?

Comment: @jan You can replace the search page with a view using exposed filters.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I was hoping I can theme the default search option for drupal using views. Because I won't be using the exposed filters and just use the default search option.

Comment: @jan If you use a view, the entire search page is replaced by the view. That is why you need to expose at least a view filter: It's what the users will use to enter the search terms. A view is just a list of nodes, and filters are used to filter the nodes that will be shown in the page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you're right. Why I did not think about it!! Thanks

Comment: any way to implement similar goal via module?

Comment: @Permana Modules can override theme functions as well.

Comment: It appears `$info_split['type']` no longer exists in D7?

Comment: @digitgopher It's `$result['node']->type`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 18):

In Drupal 7 you use ...

- [template_preprocess_search_results](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7) and
- [template_preprocess_search_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7)

... to tinker with the information displayed in the results.

And you use ...

- [search-results.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) and
- [search-result.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7)

... to customize the markup of the results.

#### Example

This is an example of how to use the content type's teaser as search result. The next snippet goes in the theme's template.php

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_search_result
 * @param type $vars
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['result']['node'];
  if ($node->nid) { // if the result is a node we can load the teaser
    $vars['teaser'] = node_view($node, 'teaser'); 
  }
}
```

This snippet is the search-result.tpl.php file:

```
<article>
  <?php if ($teaser) : // for nodes we can use the teaser as search result ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($teaser); ?>
  <?php else : // for other results we use the default from core search module ?>  
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h3>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php if ($snippet) : ?>
      <p><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($info): ?>
    <footer><?php print $info; ?></footer>
  <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

Comment: Best explanation on this thread.

Answer (score 9):

I recently spent a good deal of time working with search results on a Drupal 7 architecture website, and settled on using the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

The Display Suite module has a wonderful method for taking control of search results: It will allow you to easily use your teasers in search results. [This is a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn3e91C_2jw) by the maintainer of the module that focuses on using it for search results.

As always with Drupal, there are a variety of ways to do the same thing. I liked this method because it allowed me to break out the results by content type.

Comment: I know this answer is from 2012, but I notice that on the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) it says search functionality is now excluded in Drupal 8. Which suggests this might not be the best thing to adopt for Drupal 7, assuming you want some kind of future proofing. That's not tested by myself though, just a heads up.