# How to build my own view for apache solr module

Tags: 7, search

After successful integration of apache solr module in drupal 7 and displaying the result Ii found that it is using the view files (search-results.tpl.php & search-result.tpl.php) from the core search module to display the result.

How can I use my custom files similar to (search-results.tpl.php & search-result.tpl.php) inside the apache solr module folder to display the result?

Since I am new to drupal and just started can somebody guide me to implement it.

Comment: Do you want to build a view for apachesolr?

Comment: @ Mathankumar yes i want to build new view for apache solr

Comment: Then you can use apachesolr views module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the search-results.tpl.php & search-result.tpl.php into your theme folder. Drupal will then use these files instead of the core. If you want to pass extra variables to the search-result you can use hook_preprocess_search_result

```
function mymodule_preprocess_search_result(&$variables){
    $variables['myvariable'] = 'this is a variable pass to the search-result.tpl.php';
}
```

and then access your variables from within search-result.tpl.php like

```
print ('My variable: '.$myvariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496764/how-to-build-my-own-view-for-apache-solr-module so the answer is the same as well. Let me quote:

> The .tpl.php files are theme template files, and you can override them by using identically named files in your own theme. Some deeper reading at [Drupal docs](http://drupal.org/node/173880).
>
> Or you could use the search features provided by Google, as I did, and find [an already existing answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/4614/5678) on a related site.