# Is there a way to create custom page in panels with path "/search"?

Tags: 7, views, panels, search

Is there a way to create custom page in panels with path "/search" ?
I need to replace default drupal 7 search page with my own views page. But I can't because this path is already exist (duplicate). 
Also I can't disable "Search" module, because I use in views filter providet by search module "Search: Search Terms".
Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I customize the search result page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/how-do-i-customize-the-search-result-page)

Comment: @monymirza - I think the OP is looking more for a resolution of the path conflict than a how to on creating a new search page. Perhaps the question needs an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Search Module enabled, you should see built-in search node panel page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivailo, that's what I need.
But one more thing. Now when I'm going to "/search" page, this redirect me to "/search/node". It's possible to modify this without hacking core "search" module.?

Comment: Hi,
I would try Custom Search Module - http://drupalmodules.com/module/custom-search 

One of the advance options mention there is: multiple search paths, but I haven't use it, so I do not know if this is the best solution.