# How to show book information in search result page

Tags: nodes, search

I want to show some extra book information in the search result page like node id, book id, book name etc.
I have added some code in search-result.tpl.php but its still not showing.

```
$node->book['bid']  //is added to show book id.
$node->node['nid'] //is added to show node id.
```

Let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Check this [How do I customize the search result page?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/how-do-i-customize-the-search-result-page)

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed it using search-result.tpl.php file which copied in theme folder.

```
 $url = $variables['result']['fields']['url'];
```

this variable gives search result urls from which i extracted book name and based in book name i printed book id.
@Anil, thanks for the help which guide me at right direction and got to know many more.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the full documentation regarding [search-result.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7) .

Above documentation explains full node information is stored in $result. You can able to pull information like Node Id, Book Id, Book Name using $result variable. Use below code to print out $result variable in tpl file which you can override in your custom theme.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: I tried using $result but i am unable to get the book id and book name in it.
 Will you please tell how can i get the book name.