# Change search results pager to mini pager?

Tags: search, paging, views

How to change search result's pager to mini pager. I want to change default pager to mini pager in that search result page. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can override   [template_preprocess_search_results](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7) in your `template.php` and 
instead

```
   $variables['pager'] = theme('pager', array('tags' => NULL));
```

use

```
   $variables['pager'] = theme('views_mini_pager',array('tags' => NULL));
```

( just make sure you installed views module)
also this question can get you some clue

[How do I customize the search result page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/how-do-i-customize-the-search-result-page)

Comment: It won't work in my case. The above code would apply when we need it on form. I have search box in all the page. I have resolved this with mytheme_form_alter() function. Thank you zhilevan.

Comment: @Viraj_T your welcome I thought you need it for pager of views or your custom table :)

Comment: Ya. right zhilevan.