# how to add custom classes and div to drupal search form.. i want to change complete layout of the block

Tags: theming, search

I want to set following HTML layout in my search form.

```
   <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
<form>
    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search" type="search" value="" name="search" id="search">
    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
    <span class="sb-icon-search"><img src="<?php echo $theme_path;?>/images/search_icon.png" alt=""></span>
</form>
```

but when i render the form using module invoke i got all classes and divs that are associated with search block,i want the above HTML to be applied to my search block.

Comment: Please check this (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/how-do-i-customize-the-search-result-page ) hope this work for you!

Comment: no i want change search block's UI not search results.

Comment: Okay, then you can get details here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-block-form.tpl.php/7

Comment: Use **search-block-form.tpl.php** to change the layout of the block..